# Grepping for exact words with UNIX

Tags: unix, grep

I want to search Exact word pattern in Unix.
Example: `Log.txt` file contains following text:

```
aaa
bbb
cccaaa   ---> this should not be counted in grep output looking for aaa
```

I am using following code:

```
count=$?
count=$(grep -c aaa $EAT_Setup_BJ3/Log.txt)
```

Here output should be ==> 1 not 2, using above code I am getting 2 as output.
Something is missing, so can any one help me for the this please?

Comment: What's `count=$?` supposed to do? It certainly doesn't count the number of matches. It records grep's exit status.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Word boundary matching is an extension to the standard POSIX grep utility. It might be available or not. If you want to search for words portably, I suggest you look into perl instead, where you would use

```
perl -ne 'print if /\baaa\b/' $EAT_Setup_BJ3/Log.txt
```

Comment: This should be "/\baaa\b/" for the regex.  \W searches for a character that is NOT a word character so it can cause some odd behavior; especially if you are doing back references for matches.  \b will find a word boundary (basically the same thing but more robust and without matching a character).

Comment: @whitey04 Thank you for your helpful observation. I have adjusted the regex accordingly.

Answer (score 36):

Use whole word option:

```
grep -c  -w aaa $EAT_Setup_BJ3/Log.txt
```

From the `grep` manual:

> -w, --word-regexp
>
> Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must
>                 either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word  constituent  character.

As noted in the comment `-w` is a GNU extension. With a non GNU grep you can use the `word boundaries`:

```
grep -c "\<aaa\>" $EAT_Setup_BJ3/Log.txt
```

Comment: Note that -w is a GNUism, not a standard POSIX grep option.

Comment: Note that word boundary matching with `\<...\>` is also not POSIX. A more "portable" solution would be a perl one liner

Comment: Here I ma facing Problem with grep, I used above mentioned code :        grep -c  -w aaa $Log.txt   ==> but Its also counting for the words like : ccc-aaa etc.. I want to count only for aaa pattern srtictly only not for such, bbb-aaa or ccc_aaa patterns... so, any 1 help me please?

Comment: @Jens Yes. However, there might be cases when you *do* need to simulate word boundary anyhow, e. g. in mine, considering that (traditional) `awk` will neither support `\b` nor `\y` (the latter one being used in `gawk`). And those scripts that only work with GNU tools (and their extensions) are my pet peeve, so my regexps might sometimes look insanely complicated, but they'd need no extended regexps either.

Comment: How is using perl more portable than a GNU extended grep?  Nowhere does POSIX require perl installation.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just tried `-w` on Solaris, AIX, and Linux, and it worked on all 3. `\<\>` did not (works on Solaris, AIX doesn't like it).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a word boundary (`\b`) in regex to match an exact word. To enable extended regex, use the `-E` flag with grep.

Solution:

```
grep -E "\baaa\b" $EAT_Setup_BJ3/Log.txt
```