# Using putty/ssh and utilizing grep -rn is there a way to search exactly

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ssh, grep

For instance if i search "tom" and it finds a string called "timtom".. is there a way to filter out timtom and only find instances of tom?

I usually use grep -rn "tom" .

I've noticed it works without the period at the end too. what is the period actually for?

Although my grep search works it doesn't work exactly how i want it to.

I've also just tried grep -r
grep -i
grep -ri

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grepping for exact words with UNIX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758701/grepping-for-exact-words-with-unix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With most greps, you can use

```
grep -wrn tom .
```

The `-w` forces the match to be a complete word. The `.` means to start the recursive search in the current working directory.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Also, is there a way to copy an entire grep search without having to highlight loads of lines while dragging the mouse up or down?

Comment: @thismethod: you can redirect its output to a file, but the file will be on the machine on which grep is running. PuTTY has file transfer capabilities iirc.

Comment: That works well, I've got one more question if you don't mind. Sometimes when i do -rn or -wrn i get back big blocks of code instead of just file paths and the line number the instance is on... is there a way to get rid of those big blocks of code and ONLY get back the file paths and the number of the line the instance is on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @thismethod I have no idea why you would get big blocks printed out. The only thing I can think of is that you are somehow ending up with versions of files with line-endings removed, but how or why that happens is very difficult to guess from a distance. if you specify -rn, then every line printed out will start with a filename and line number, although the line might split over several (or even many) display lines; you will have to find the beginning of the line to see which file it is, and then you should have a clue as to what to do about it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, i think that might be the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a space and search " tom" instead of "tom".

grep -E "^tom| tom"

exlpanation :

-E make use of regular expressions,

^ means 'start of line'

| means LOGICAL-OR

which can read as : match a line start with 'tom' OR have ' tom' which is 'tom' without any leading chars.

Comment: What exactly does that do and how does it work?

Comment: the space before "tom" makes it " tom". and " tom" is not in "timtom" ( " " is not "m").

Comment: This approach isn't so good - for example it will miss a "tom" at the beginning of the line. I recommend using [option -w](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Matching-Control) as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15758759/3982001) (though it must be noted that those options are GNU, not POSIX)

Comment: Thanks Fabio. i edit the answer to include your comment.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, sure there is, to avoid `tim` and `tom` together, only find lines containing a word starting with `tom` try

```
grep -ir '\<tom'
```

- `-i` for case insensitive search
- `\<` to match when there is a beginning of word. Note if you wanted to omit entries like `tommy` `tomato` where `tom` is followed by something, then you need to match word end too via `\<tom\>`
- `-r` for recursive search in current directory
- grep by default is a line-filtering tool so it shows you a line that matches your pattern, whatever else is on that same line, so if you want to see no other words and literally only `tom` by itself there is the `-o` option

*Updated:* removed irrelevant part of answer about about period, thanks @Fabio

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question: the period he was talking about is *outside* of the regular expression, not *inside*. rici has already explained what it does in that case.