# AIX sh, how to grep an expression with double quotes in a string?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, grep

I need to find in a log, all lines containing a server name.
So I do in my script :

```
    grep $x ./input_log_files.csv >> test.txt
```

where x contain the server name.

The problem is that this way, I also trap lines that contain the server name in a longer name. To be clear, we have here a AIXserver, and also a virtual server called VAIXserver. So when I search the first one, I get the other one too.
In my log file, the server name in surrounded by double quotes. I'm desperately trying to grep on the server name WITH the double quotes. I also tryed with the commas such as in ,"AIXserver", with no success.

How can I force grep to consider the double quotes ?
I tryed with singl quotes, escape characters ... with no success.

Thx for your help.
B²

Comment: Just encapsulate the double quotes within single quotes, so the single quotes define the string, with the double quotes intact, like: `grep '"AIXserver"' ./input_log_files.csv`. Should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the variable contains the quotes:

```
x='"sname"'
```

And use it quoted:

```
$ testval=$'sname\nVsname\n"sname"\n"Vsname"\n"sname2"'

$ echo "$testval"
sname
Vsname
"sname"
"Vsname"
"sname2"

$ echo "$testval" | grep "$x"
"sname"
```

For your command line:

```
grep "$x" ./input_log_files.csv >> test.txt
```

Comment: Thx. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -w $x ./input_log_files.csv >> test.txt
```

alternate option

```
perl -ne 'print if /\b$x\b/' ./input_log_files.csv >> test.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Caburse ! Working like a charm ! That was so simple !

Comment: My bad, it's working only with the begining. A server name with a suffix is also badly detected. So Vservername is not detected as servername, but servername2 is detected as servername.

Comment: Maybe check the value of x? I tested this matches the exact word. This link has some alternate options just in case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758701/grepping-for-exact-words-with-unix